# How to add CSS for a sub theme?

Tags: theming, 9

I have a sub theme I created this way:

**globalrs/globalrs.info.yml**

```
name: globalrs
type: theme
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
description: globalrs
base theme: tara
libraries:
  - globalrs/global-styling
```

**globalrs/globalrs.libraries.yml**

```
global-styling:
  css:
    component:
      css/style.css: {}
```

**globalrs/style/style.css**

```
* {
    background: red !important;
}
```

The sub theme was set to default but still nothing has a red background (after flushing browser cache). What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme#attach-library-all-pages), you want to use `theme` instead of `component`:

```
global-styling:
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
```

Also note in addition to flushing the browser cache, you should [rebuild the Drupal cache](https://drupalize.me/tutorial/clear-drupals-cache?p=2512).